# It is possible to get functionality similar to .NET's LINQ in C++?

Tags: c++, linq

It is possible to get functionality similar to .NET's LINQ in C++? Would this require language extensions or could it be done using some very clever macros? Or even through a tool like Qt's moc (meta-object compiler)? Are there any existing LINQ implementations for C++ and if so, what are they?

Comment: Your question shouldn't be "How do I get a feature from language X into language Y". That's a pointless question, they're different languages, learn how language Y does things. Ask "How can I solve problem A in language Y?"

Comment: @GMan: LINQ is quite a nice feature to have, even for a language as low level as C++.

Comment: @GMan: Do you like the `algorithms` in STL - `accumulate`, `transform`, `partial_sum` etc? Well, LINQ is just a step further in that direction. LINQ provides far more power than STL algorithms, and is arguably far more legible.

Comment: @Cheryl: Where did I say it wouldn't be useful? The point is it's *not* useful trying to get a language to do something it's not assisting you in doing. When someone programs in language X, they should forget everything about any other languages. Embrace your language, don't try to turn it into some other language.

Comment: @GMan: _"When someone programs in language X, they should forget everything about any other languages."_ << That's the most absurd statement I have heard from anyone on StackOverflow. And I completely disagree with it.

Comment: @GMan: _"Embrace your language, don't try to turn it into some other language."_ << If boost people would have shown this attitude, we wouldn't have `boost::lambda`, `boost::parameters`, `boost::phoenix` etc today. All these libraries try to emulate the features that are natively supported in some other languages.

Comment: @Cheryl: Why is it absurd? Most of the stupid questions asked in the C++ section begin with "I know Java, and in Java you do this...". All Boost does is wrap up "the C++ way" into a cleaner method (generate functors instead of explicitly make them, generate methods of extracting parameters instead of doing them by hand), they don't try to say "In Java, or in C# you do this, so C++ will do this to copy Java or C#." If OP wants to query data, he should ask how to query data in the clean way *in C++*. And if it *happens* to be similar to LINQ, then so be it. But don't go for it directly.

Comment: @GMan: What is so stupid about asking questions about parallel idioms in some other language?!

Comment: @GMan: You should always try to borrow good ideas from other languages. C++ has got a very rich template system that can allow you to emulate useful idioms from other languages. Do you not like `boost::lambda`? It was created in attempt to emulate lambdas found in functional languages like Haskell.

Comment: @Cheryl: If a problem can be solved elegantly in language X via some approach, that doesn't mean transposing the approach into language Y is going to be elegant. A trivial example is SBRM (RAII) in C++, versus `finally` blocks in C#. If you want a solution to a problem in some language, then ask for a solution to the problem for that language. I don't know how else to put it, and I honestly don't really care anymore. The point is if you want to program C#, then just program in C#.

Comment: @GMan: RAII vs `finally` is a semantics-dependent example. RAII fits well with the semantics of the C++ language, `finally` doesn't. `finally` fits well with the semantics of C#, RAII doesn't. That is the example where borrowing or trying to emulate idea from some other language is not advised.

Comment: @GMan: _"I don't know how else to put it, and I honestly don't really care anymore."_ << Such bigotted attitude is very common in monoglot upstarts. As you go along in your programming journey for a few years and have a experience with multiple languages, your opinions on this topic are very likely to change (saying from my own experience :).

Comment: @Cheryl: That's the point. LINQ might not necessarily be the best approach to a problem in C++. If it is, then asking the question "How do I do X in C++?" Will be "A LINQ-like" approach. If it isn't, it won't be. The point is, you don't *assume* a solution then ask how to solve your problem in it, you ask about your problem and see the solution.

Comment: @Cheryl: I don't care because I'm extremely sick and not in the mood to try and convince you that in my experience with helping people program C++, most problems occur because people assume a solution (because it worked in some other language) and can't see why C++ isn't that some other language. Actually programming C++ in C++ is surprisingly effective, and dropping what people think they know is the only way to program good C++; the elegant solutions fall in place. If they happen to correlate to an approach in some other languages, whoopty-doo.

Comment: A "here's my solution, what's the problem" approach is backwards.

Comment: @GMan The greatest flaw in your argument is that you're trying too hard to generalize. Your argument in *this particular situation* is unfounded. LINQ is a very powerful feature which needn't be unique to .NET languages - and it's not. LINQ *is* the best way to solve the problems it's designed to solve (e.g. projecting and filtering data in sets and other sources) and there's no reason to say "use C#" whenever these problems are encountered. "Use C#" is not a valid solution - there are reasons I and many others cannot do that in our various specific situations.

Comment: If only C# had `if` statements, would you complain if someone said other languages should have them too? LINQ specifically, is something that fits well with many different languages. I *do* use the right tool for the job. And here, it's not C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check CLinq ([here](http://tomasp.net/blog/clinq-project.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/clinq.aspx)) or Linq++ ([here](http://hjiang.net/archives/229)).
Also try p-stade ([here](http://p-stade.sourceforge.net/oven/doc/html/index.html)); however, it uses the STL and it doesn't have the same interface as LINQ, but it's pretty complete.

Comment: CLinq is for C++/CLI, and C++/CLI ≠ C++.

Comment: @Missing Faktor: The techniques that I used in the implementation of CLinq would work in plain C++ too. It is in C++/CLI only because I wanted to use the existing .NET API (LINQ libraries), but that could be reimplemented in C++. CLinq is pretty much implemented just using templates (not generics :-)) and usual operator overloading.

Answer (score 2):

With this [Linq](http://pfultz2.github.com/Linq/) library for C++11, you can do list comprehension using linq-like syntax:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
auto r = LINQ(from(x, numbers) where(x > 2) select(x * x));
for (auto x : r) printf("%i\n", x);
```

It uses the preprocessor to parse out the `from`, `where`, and `select` clauses, and converts it to the equivalent of this using [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) adaptors:

```
auto r = numbers 
        | boost::adaptors::filtered([](int x) { return x > 2; }) 
        | boost::adaptors::transformed([](int x) { return x * x; });
```

Answer (score 1):

> > It is possible to get functionality similar to .NET's LINQ in C++? Would this require language extensions or could it be done using some very clever macros?

C++ macros aren't powerful enough to implement something as complex as LINQ.

To implement LINQ-like system in the form of library, the language needs:

- Good embedded-DSL capabilities.
- Lazy evaluation
- Persistent collections
- Lambda expressions

Embedded DSLs in C++ look very ugly thanks to the rigorous syntax and semantics of the language (for example, look at Boost.Spirit and then look at an equivalent library from a DSL-friendly language like Haskell). You can get lazy evaluation via `boost::phoenix`. There is no persistent collections library available for C++ (apart from FC++, which is pretty incomplete). Lambda Expressions are coming to C++ in the next standard of the language.

Even if someday someone manages to create a LINQ-like system for C++ using above-mentioned ingredients, that system won't be as good as LINQ in .NET. So yes, it is *possible*, but *not very practical*. :)

> > Or even through a tool like Qt's moc (meta-object compiler)?

This is very much possible. But then it won't still really be C++, will it? ;)

> > Are there any existing LINQ implementations for C++ and if so, what are they?

A few attempts have been made in this direction (as pointed out by other gentleman here). None of them comes close to the "real" LINQ, but they're still worth having a look at. :)

**EDIT:**
Apparently I was wrong about the "practical" bit. Look at the p-stade link in Yassin's answer, which is a great example of what can be achieved with clever use of powerful C++ abstractions. :-)

Comment: I would disagree with this in so far as you could get by with a builder pattern: `mybuilder.select("Trees").from("Sprites").where("Height > 4");`

Comment: @wheaties: And what would you do with those strings? To do anything useful with those strings, you'd need reflection - something that C++ doesn't have.

Comment: @Cheryl Vincent I think that would work pretty darned well for LINQ on SQL.

Comment: @wheaties: ...and what about LINQ on collections?

Comment: You mean it's actually not worth the trouble to try and implement a LINQ approach to a problem in C++, because C++ isn't a language with LINQ? Wow. A new approach might be to see what C++ can do and explore that direction, taking advantage of what it *does* have to offer.

Comment: @GMan: Have a look at p-stade link in Yassin's answer. Looks quite nice and useful.